# To be all over the place - what does it mean?

Tags: meaning

e.g. in

"I'm all over the place to day"

"She's all over the place"

Comment: Moving in diverse directions.

Comment: It is really just a metaphor for saying that you feel confused and/or disorganised.

Comment: I just hope the 2nd example isn't to be taken literally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It implies inconsistency or lack of uniformity. ie not in one place but jumping around everywhere. It can be used not only relating to location though, for example;

"His answers were all over the place" ie not sticking to the question or a consistent line of reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

It has two common meanings

> 1. [informal] Everywhere: *we’ve been all over the place looking for you*
> 2. In a state of disorder:
>      *my hair was all over the place*

[*Oxford Dictionaries Online*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/all-over-the-place-or-map)

In the examples you have offered, the second meaning seems more apt.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the context.

It can be akin to being [scattered](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/scattered)

> 2. Not thinking clearly or in an organized fashion; unfocused (AHDEL)

It can be used of actions, thinking, moods, etc. The meaning of your sentence depends on the context in which it was used.

> What's going on with her today? She's all over the place. Nothing is getting done.

That would be in line with her attentions being scattered.

On Marilyn Monroe's birthday, one might say

> Can't get away from Marilyn Monroe today; she's all over the place.

That would mean her presence (in pictures, stories, etc.) was everywhere.

Context matters. If it's from a song, look at the rest of the words.

Answer (score 0):

In the meaning you're using, it simply means distracted, unable to focus.